# PHP - How to group multi-dimensional array with keys and values

Tags: php

I attempted to ask this question earlier but did not provide enough information...

I am pulling information out of a database. Each row that I pull looks like this,

```
{"group":"admin","center":"equipment","section":"bucket","tab":"overview"}
```

I need the following information, "Center", "section", and "tab".

Currently, I use "array_push" to create an array with this info. The code looks like this,

```
for ($y=0;$y<count($infos);$y++){
    $templist = array();
    array_push($templist, $infos[$y]['center']);
    array_push($templist, $infos[$y]['section']);
    array_push($templist, $infos[$y]['tab']);
    array_push($tempmasterlist, $templist);
```

and displays this when I use json_encode()

```
[["center1","section1","tab1"],["center2","section1","overview"],["center1","section1","tab2"]]
```

I need the resulting json to look like this,

```
 {"center1":["section1",["tab1", "tab2"]],"center2":["section1",["tab3"]]}
```

Basically, I want to dynamically group these properly so that they can be easily retrieved.
A center can have multiple sections, and a section can have multiple tabs. Depending on the user, there can be multiple centers, sections, or tabs so I am not able to hardcode anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been driving myself crazy with for loops and if statements for hours...

Comment: can a center have more than 1 section?

Comment: Yes, Center A can have section b, c, and d. Each section can have multiple tabs.

Comment: Are you sure about the resulting json format? Shouldn't tabs be descendents of sections?

Comment: are `tab1` and `tab2` sub elements of `section1`? In your example, what if you have a another section (i.e. `section2`) under `center1`, how would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `array_push`. You can just use the appropriate column from your result rows as keys in `$tempmasterlist`.

```
foreach ($infos as $row) {
    $tempmasterlist[$row['center']][$row['section']][] = $row['tab'];
}
```

Comment: interesting, so if I had `$templist = array()`, then by doing `$templist['hello']['my']['buddy'][] = 'foo'` I would have a multi dimensional array with 4 layers directly?

Comment: @linuxisthebest33 Please don't write a separate answer. If this answer worked for you then *accept* it. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: @Webeng technically, `$templist` would not even need to be defined beforehand.